# How to extract the property values of a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, console.log

How can I extract the following value of the variable Test?
"test_bookmarks", "Janice Scott", "Birmingham all" from the `javascript` object into another variable?

The image comes from the console log of Google Chrome.

[image]

Comment: e.$$state.value[0].label

Comment: Can you post the Object rather than posting an image?

Comment: Right click on the property you want and chose `copy property path`

Comment: I don't have a path of a variable.

Comment: e.$$state.value[0].label don't run

Comment: @Bombo: Check my answer. It will run because I am enclosing property name in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the value of "value" key, it tells you that it is an array. That means the if you do something like:

```
$$state.value[*].label
```

here * stands for any integer, this way you'll get the values of the label property.

So, if you want to access the first label then it would be like:

```
$$state.value[0].label
```

this will give you "test_bookmarks".

Answer (score 1):

```
let states = e.$$state.value;
let labels = states.map(state => state.label); //[ 'test_bookmarks', 'Janice Scott', 'Birmingham_bil' ]
```

Comment: Did you try this ?

Comment: indeed, it answers OP's need : `extract the values into a variable`

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i=0; i<=e["$$state"].value.length-1; i++) {
    var obj = e["$$state"].value[i];
    console.log(obj.label);
}
```

Comment: sorry I didn't  specify that the object js is inside a variable  for example   "test"

Comment: @Bombo: Do you mean `test.e["$$state"].value`?

Comment: The variabile "test " contains the image object